# use buffer_protocol() in pybind11 for a custom class

Tags: python, c++, numpy, binding, pybind11

I have a templated class and I have a method inside this class that return a pointer of the raw buffer.

I tried to use buffer_protocol to return a numpy array directly in python side from the raw buffer.

This way works well for standard types (float, int double, string, etc ..) but I need to used it for a custom type.

```
template < class T>
class Array1D { 
public:
    
     Array1D()
     {
         Init();
     }
    
     Array1D(const uint32_t size)
     {
         Init();
         SetSize(size);
     }
    
     Array1D(const  Array1D<T> &obj)
     {
         Init();
         *this = obj;
     }
    
     const T& operator[](uint32_t n)const
     {
         S_ASSERT((n < m_nSize));
         return m_pData[n];
     }
    
     T& operator[](uint32_t n)
     {
         S_ASSERT((n < m_nSize));
         return m_pData[n];
     }
    
     
     inline const T* GetBuffer()const
     {
         return m_pData;
     }
    
     inline T* GetBuffer()
     {
         return m_pData;
     }
    protected: 
         T*m_pData; 
         uint32_t m_nSize;
         uint32_t m_nCapacity;
         bool m_bDeleteBuffer; 
    };
```

I used this code to bind what I say above :

```
 .def_buffer([](Array1D<T> &m)->py::buffer_info {
    
    return py::buffer_info(m.GetBuffer(), sizeof(T), 
    
    py::format_descriptor<T>::format(), 1, {m.GetSize()}, {sizeof(T)}); });
```

It works well when I call my module like this :

```
export_Array1D<S_INT8>(m, "S_INT8");
export_Array1D<float>(m, "float");
```

But when I tried this :

```
 export_Array1D<MyOwnClass>(m, "MyOwnClass");
```

I have this error :

```
error: ‘format’ is not a member of ‘pybind11::format_descriptor<MyOwnClass, void>’
```

Anyone can help me to resolve this error ?

Thank you